# Open balls in normed space

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space. Let the open ball $B(x,r_1)$ in $X$ be contained in the open ball $B(y,r_2)$. If $r_1=r_2$, how can I show that $x=y$? Geometrically, it is ok for me but how to write a mathematical proof of it?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/P-adic_Norm_is_Norm

Answer (score 2):

If those balls are equal, then their closures are equal too. That is
$$
(\forall z\in X):\|z-x\|\le r_1\iff\|z-y\|\le r_2.
$$

If $x\neq y$, consider the points of the form $(1-t)x+ty$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$
\left\|\bigl((1-t)x+ty\bigr)-x\right\|=|t|\|x-y\|.
$$
So, if $t=-\dfrac{r_1}{\|x-y\|}$, then $(1-t)x+ty$ belongs to the closed ball centered at $x$ with radius $r_1$. So, it should also belong to the closed ball centered at $y$ with radius $r_2(=r_1)$. But it does not, since
\begin{align}
\left\|\bigl((1-t)x+ty\bigr)-y\right\|&=\left(1+\frac{r_1}{\|x-y\|}\right)\|x-y\|\\
&=\|x-y\|+r_1\\
&>r_1.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x \neq y$. Note that $x \in B(y,r)$ so $\|x-y\|<r$. If $0<t<\frac r {\|x-y\|}$ and $t >\frac r {\|x-y\|}-1$ then $x-t(y-x)$ belongs to the first ball but not the second. [Check that such a number $t$ exists!].

Comment: This is a bit suspicious since $t\to 0^+$ satisfies your requirements. We have
$$\|(x-t(y-x))-y\| = (1+t)\|x-y\| > \left(2-\frac{r}{\|x-y\|}\right)\|x-y\| = 2\|x-y\|-r$$
but the latter expression is $< r$, not $\ge r$.

Comment: @mechanodroid There was  a typo. I meant t say $t>\frac r {\|x-y\|}-1$ and not $t >1-\frac r {\|x-y\|}$. Note that $\frac r {\|x-y\|}-1>0$ and that  $t$ is not allowed to be close to $0$.

Comment: Now it seems ok, nice solution. I think you can actually just take $t = \frac{r}{\|x-y\|}-1$, then $x-t(y-x)$ belongs to $B(x,r)$ but is precisely on the boundary of $B(y,r)$ so it doesn't belong to it.

Comment: @mechanodroid Yes, you are right.